# linux echo/print removing 1 space in string when printing multiple variables

Tags: linux, scripting, echo, ksh

When I try to echo or print a string, it prints fine.

This is the string.

```
IP_NET_TP0                                                                               _
```

The structure is IP_NET_TP0, and 9 tabs (\t), then 7 spaces and 1 underscore at the end.

Ok, if you put that into a variable, let's say var1 and you print it as follows it works great.

```
echo $var1 
echo "$var1"
```

BUT, if you add extra texts to it, for example, adding quotes, or adding a letter, it removes 1 space from the chain.

```
echo \"$var1\" 
echo "'"$var1"'"
echo "a" $var1
```

WHY?! .. I have tried printing the variable with print, or like this ${var1}, and the output if the same, with 1 space less.

The following shows, the first one when printed with something else, and the second when printed alone.

```
IP_NET_TP0                                                                             _
IP_NET_TP0                                                                               _
```

Any help will be great.

Comment: Try with `printf` (which is also a command, even a [bash builtin](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf))

Comment: It was a good one but, the same results, I am using 
`printf "\"%s\"" "${mat[c][0]}"`
I changed my var name to mat[][], but the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue fixed, as the string was built converting spaces to tabs, there are tabs with different sizes! ... causing probably an interpretation issue when printed, what I did was, before printing the variable, convert all the tabs to spaces so the size won't change any more like this `var2=`echo $var1 | expand` ... and done, the size is now fixed and it is not going to change any more.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are instantiating the variable incorrectly. When I declare it like this `var1="IP_NET_TP0"` or `var1=IP_NET_TP0` printing it the ways you did works fine. Are you using bash or a different type of shell? There might also be something weird in your .bash_profile or .bashrc causing this.

Comment: I am using KSH ..., and I am still trying to make this thing to work correctly

Comment: I'm not getting this problem when instantiating the var1 the way I mentioned above. How are you declaring the variable with this value? That may be the error. If that isn't it, it might be something with the way your shell is configured.

Comment: The var1 is coming from a sql query, and it is coming with all those tabs and spaces, as I said, if I just print it, it works, but if I add something else to what I am going to print, it fails the way I described.

Comment: Try statically grabbing that value just like you copied and pasted it into your question, assign it to a variable and see if the same thing happens. If not, then something must be incorrect when assigning the variable to the sql query result.

Comment: same thing my friend...
What I just noticed actually typing the string is, that my first tab is shorter then the rest of tabs, let me try to overcome that and see what happens.

Comment: Issue fixed, as the string was built converting spaces to tabs, there are tabs with different sizes! ... causing probably an interpretation issue when printed, what I did was, before printing the variable, convert all the tabs to spaces so the size won't change any more like this `var2=`echo $var1 | expand` ... and done, the size is now fixed and it is not going to change any more.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't write the echo correctly when adding the extra patterne

```
echo \"$var1\" -> echo "\"$var1\""
echo "'"$var1"'" -> echo "'$var1'"
echo "a" $var1 -> echo "a $var1"  #if space is needed between a and the var1
```

also try to use ${var1} to avoid confusion when like this

```
var="1 x 1 = "
var1="Something"
echo "$var1"
echo "${var}1"
echo "${var1}"
```

Comment: All the options are well written, they are interpreted in line correctly, and those are just some of the different prints that I have tried. The results are the same with all the echos, prints, printfs that I have tried, between quotes, without them, with {}, etc, haha I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Issue fixed by using expand.

Comment: are you sur it is missing ? I test here and character are present but due to \t seem missing. Check with a |wc -c to see how much char